# using data from datasource to for initWithFrame in subview

Tags: objective-c, initialization, datasource

I am creating  subview class that gets information about its frame from its datasource. I would like to create a custom initialization method that takes a object which implements the datasource protocol as an argument. One of the datasource protocol methods, frameSize, has the datasource return a CGrect. My question is if it is possible to set the datasource in a custom initialization before calling [super initWithFrame]? This is what I have:

```
-(id) initWithDataSource:(id)dataSource
{
self._dataSource=dataSource;
[super initWithFrame:[self._dataSource frameSize];
return self;
}
```

Its seems counterintuitive to me to set a property before calling the initialization method. Is there a good way to do this, or is it feasible to initialize it with an empty frame and then set the frame later? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An init method must always assign `self = [super initXXX]`, because the super init method might return a value different from the original `self`.

But you could call `initWithFrame:` with a dummy rect first and assign the actual frame after `self` is initialized:

```
-(id) initWithDataSource:(id)dataSource
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
    if (self) {
        self._dataSource = dataSource;
        self.frame = [self._dataSource frameSize];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest going a different way, instead of using a temporary rectangle, and then moving things around.  Remember that there's nothing stopping you from using the datasource before it's actually assigned as a property (though add the protocol declaration to make the compiler happy).

Here's how I'd do this:

```
-(id) initWithDataSource: (id<MyDataSourceProtocol>) ds {
    self = [super initWithFrame: [ds frameSize]];
    self.dataSource = ds;
    return self;
}
```